# Changing what keyboard keys do, e.g. 'Alt gr + z' producing | rather than «

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

My keyboard is not programmer friendly so I want to manually change how some keys work:

<kbd>Alt gr</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> should produce `|` not `«`

<kbd>Alt gr</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> should produce `<` not `»`

<kbd>Alt gr</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> should produce `>` not `¢`

How would I go about doing that?

---

```
$ setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     is,us
variant:    ,
```

Comment: what is the output of `setxkbmap -query` in terminal?

Comment: @Andra I've included it in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is a quite difficult way: [editing the keyboard layout files](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions?action=show&redirect=Howto%3A%20Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions). The link refers to the Ubuntu documentation. Although the edit itself would be minimal to do what you want, how to find the keys and where to edit is more tricky to get your head around. Still, a little specific help with the one of the edits:

The keycode for <kbd>z</kbd> is 52 on my system as seen using the `xev` tool. As indicated in the file /usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev, that corresponds with the scancode `<AB01>`. Locate that key in your keyboard layout file, e.g. for me, `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols`, and adapt the third field, which stands for the combination with <kbd>AltGr</kbd>:

```
key <AB01> { [     z,          Z,   Greek_OMEGA,     dead_cedilla ] };
```

becomes

```
key <AB01> { [     z,          Z,   bar,             dead_cedilla ] };
```

`bar` is also found from `xev`, or can be found in `/usr/include/X11/keysymdef.h`